# Crowd Rest API usage

Tags: rest, atlassian-crowd

I am trying to add 100 of users to a group in crowd and I want to automate it using curl and crowd's rest api. At first I am just trying to add a singleuser to a group and then auotmate it using shell script. Following [this document](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/CROWDDEV/Crowd+REST+Resources),  I pass the command as

```
curl -X POST{"name":"groupname"} -ik -u application:password-H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' https://localhost/crowd/rest/usermanagement/1/user/group/direct?username=username.
```

I am getting the following error.

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Embedded-Crowd-Version: Crowd/2.8.3
X-Crowd-User-Management-Version: 1.4
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=17490A660F9A2267B378CD767CEADDF8; Path=/crowd/; Secure; HttpOnly
Allow: HEAD,DELETE,POST,GET,OPTIONS
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Language: en
Content-Length: 1013
Date: Mon, 29 Jun 2015 02:56:15 GMT
```

FYI: I am using a application to authenticate against crowd via rest. Please suggest on what I need to do and how should I do.

P.S. I also need to figure out on adding hudreds of groups to crowd too.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a space between POST and your data.

To post data use:

> -d, --data
>
> (HTTP) Sends the specified data in a POST request to the HTTP server,
>   in the same way that a browser does when a user has filled in an HTML
>   form and presses the submit button. This will cause curl to pass the
>   data to the server using the content-type
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Compare to -F, --form.

So the command should be:

```
curl -X POST -d {"name":"groupname"} -ik -u application:password -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' https://localhost/crowd/rest/usermanagement/1/user/group/direct?username=username
```

From Crowds Docs,

> Authentication Access to all resources (using any method) requires the
>   client to be authenticated via basic authentication. See RFC 2617.
>
> Your environment must retain cookies set by the Crowd server and
>   retransmit them on subsequent calls, otherwise Crowd will have to
>   re-authenticate the application on every REST call.

So first authenticate your self and store the cookies, (make note of --cookie-jar parameter)

```
curl -i -u application_name:application_password --data '{"value": "my_password"}' http://localhost:8095/crowd/rest/usermanagement/1/authentication?username=my_username --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' --cookie-jar cookies.txt
```

So as per docs on subsequent calls use the cookies (using --cookie parameter)

```
curl -X POST -d {"name":"groupname"} -ik -u application:password -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' https://localhost/crowd/rest/usermanagement/1/user/group/direct?username=username --cookie cookies.txt
```

Comment: Hi Yash, thank you for your help. One more question, Do my username have to be an admin for the crowd instance and what kind of application user name and password should i be using? Thanks again.

Comment: This is the way i did: curl -k -s -X POST -d '{"name":"admin-users"}' -u username:password -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' "https://localhost.com/crowd/rest/usermanagement/1/user/group/direct?username=user"  which fixed my concern.